# scrollbar and alignment issue with JavaFX web view

Tags: javafx, webview

I am using Javafx webview to embed a webpage inside a standalone Java application. The application has a small frame size of 415 by 180. I would like the top left hand corner of the webpage to appear in the top left corner of the jfxPanel. For some reason the webpage LHS appears further to the left of my jfxPanel LHS. I could tweak the page with css to indent the page but was wondering if there is an easy way to solve this in my java code?

Also, the scroll bars have disappeared. I only need the vertical scroll bar. Any ideas what I need to change so that I can have a vertical scroll bar?

In my main java program I have:

```
JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
browser browser = new browser(jPanel);                           
browser.loadURL("http://www.url.com");
jtp.addTab("tab", jPanel);
```

The bowser class is:

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView; 
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


public class browser extends JFrame {

    private final JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    private WebEngine engine;
    private JPanel panel;

    public browser(JPanel panel) {
        super();
        this.panel = panel;
        initComponents();
    }


    private void initComponents() {

        createScene();

        panel.add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    private void createScene() {

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override 
            public void run() {

                WebView view = new WebView();
                engine = view.getEngine();


                jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(view));
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadURL(final String url) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override 
            public void run() {
                String tmp = toURL(url);

                if (tmp == null) {
                    tmp = toURL("http://" + url);
                }

                engine.load(tmp);
            }
        });
    }

    private static String toURL(String str) {
        try {
            return new URL(str).toExternalForm();
        } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
                return null;
        }
    }


}
```